# How to convert dict into array of objects in python

Tags: python

I have a dict list `dict(streams_list)` which gives values example- `{'Generic': ['_96_fkGECEeyqHrLeykGtFQ'], 'SF1B': ['_9lG7AJ8PEey0L88pC_veNw']}`

How can I convert this to array of objects ? example -

`[{'Generic': '_96_fkGECEeyqHrLeykGtFQ'}, {'SF1B': '_9lG7AJ8PEey0L88pC_veNw'},....]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this:

```
my_dict = {'Generic': ['_96_fkGECEeyqHrLeykGtFQ'], 'SF1B': ['_9lG7AJ8PEey0L88pC_veNw']}
my_list = [{k:v[0]} for k,v in my_dict.items()]
```

Result:

```
{'Generic': '_96_fkGECEeyqHrLeykGtFQ'}, {'SF1B': '_9lG7AJ8PEey0L88pC_veNw'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dict = {'Generic': ['_96_fkGECEeyqHrLeykGtFQ'], 'SF1B': ['_9lG7AJ8PEey0L88pC_veNw']}

result = [{key: values[0]} for key, values in dict.items()]

print(result)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using indexing you could use some variable unpacking magic:

```
data = {'Generic': ['_96_fkGECEeyqHrLeykGtFQ'], 'SF1B': ['_9lG7AJ8PEey0L88pC_veNw']}    
result = [{k, v} for k, (v,) in data.items()]
```

---

```
[{'Generic', '_96_fkGECEeyqHrLeykGtFQ'}, {'SF1B', '_9lG7AJ8PEey0L88pC_veNw'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Inferred input that you are using:

```
streams_list: list[tuple[str, list[str]]] = [
    ('Generic', ['_96_fkGECEeyqHrLeykGtFQ']),
    ('SF1B', ['_9lG7AJ8PEey0L88pC_veNw']),
]
```

Test defining your requested behavior:

```
def test_transform():
    expected_output: list[dict[str, str]] = [
        {'Generic': '_96_fkGECEeyqHrLeykGtFQ'},
        {'SF1B': '_9lG7AJ8PEey0L88pC_veNw'},
    ]
    actual_output = transform(input=streams_list)
    assert all(
        expected_dict in actual_output
        for expected_dict in expected_output
    )
```

One implementation that passes said test:

```
def transform(input: list[tuple[str, list[str]]]) -> list[dict[str, str]]:
    output: list[dict[str, str]] = []
    for pair in input:
        key: str
        val: list[str]
        key, val = pair
        output.append({key: val[0]})
    return output
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve your question, try the following code:

```
your_dictionary = {'Generic': ['_96_fkGECEeyqHrLeykGtFQ'], 'SF1B': ['_9lG7AJ8PEey0L88pC_veNw']}
your_list = [{your_object:object_key[0]} for your_object, object_key in your_dictionary.items()]
print(your_list)
```

Output:

```
{'Generic': '_96_fkGECEeyqHrLeykGtFQ'}, {'SF1B': '_9lG7AJ8PEey0L88pC_veNw'}]
```